# Grails sort an existing collection by date

Tags: sorting, grails

I am trying to sort a collection by dateCreated desc but i cant seem to do it.

What i have tried so far:

```
 postOrder.sort({
            dateCreated: 'desc'
        })

 postOrder.sort(dateCreated: 'asc')
```

any ideas??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
postOrder.sort{ it.dateCreated } //asc

postOrder.sort{ it.dateCreated }.reverse() //desc
```

Comment: postOrder.sort{ -it.dateCreated } //desc - a bit cleaner

Comment: Personally i like the .reverse() a bit more, this seems more expressive and easier to read.

Comment: reverse didn't seem to work for me. i reverted to reading the collection in backwards and building it back up

Comment: Just another suggestion, if this is the field that you always sort on desc, you might better off to put 'sort dateCreated:"desc"' in your domain mapping, so that grails return the result always in that order.